# How to disable/enable submit button in parent component when form is in its ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form-modal component:

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"
     (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    </button>
</div>

<ng-content #form></ng-content>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-danger" (click)="onCancel()">
        Cancel
      </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-success" type="submit" form="formModal" [disabled]="form.formModalGroup?.invalid">
        Save
      </button>
</div>
```

ng-content itself holds the specific form. The question is how to get the formGroup validity status from the ng-content to this parent form-modal component. I have tried bubbling an event from the specific form component, also @ContentChild, and I also have come up with this very similar question:

[Disable/Enable submit button in parent component when forms are in child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563032/disable-enable-submit-button-in-parent-component-when-forms-are-in-child-compone)

But that fix doesn't seem to work when adding the reference directly to the ng-content tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with a `@ContentChild`, in your TS :

```
@ContentChild(YourComponentType, {static: true}) childComponent:YourComponentType;
```

In your HTML:

```
[disabled]="!childComponent || childComponent.formModalGroup?.invalid"
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this. It was my first choice actually. But it continues saying that it cannot read property formModalGroup of undefined.

Comment: yes maybe because when the component is initializing it is not defined yet. Maybe add this extra condition: [disabled]="!childComponent || childComponent.formModalGroup?.invalid"

Answer (score 0):

As I've seen on your code, you are facing a common problem where we all have been: communicating between parent/child/siblings...

If you want to react to changes in the validity of the form in your TS file, I could see 2 main options:

- Use `@ContentChild`:

```
@ContentChild("form", {static: false}) form;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    // here now you can access to the form instance, and subscribe to changes on the status
    this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(
        result => console.log(result)
    );

  }
```

Full example on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49666202/6852402

- Consider using a shared service between 2 components, and make use of a `BehaviorSubject` observable. `BehaviorSubject` is the foundation of state libraries based on RxJs.

Here you can see a full explanation and example: https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc